# Working with core data and table view cell in mastered detail application

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

​

I'm designing an app to store data locally on the phone and I'm using core data. I'm using master detailed application app type because the app is kind of likes notes app but with many UITextField for strong data.

So I have many three view controllers

MasterViewController

(This view controller has only one typical cell view with just title for the cell and a add huston on top which takes the user to DetailedVIewController )

DetailedView Controller

(This view controller has 5-6 UITextField with takes input from the user, one button to add images from camera roll and one UITextfield which automatically populates the gps coordinates. There is a save button which saves all the data entered by the user and back button to go back to the MasterViewController)

StorageViewController

(This view controller will display all the data in respective fields  as entered by the user in DetailedViewController. Each time the user saves there is a new cell created in masterviewcontroller and by clicking the individual cell the user can access that file.)

I've designed all the app and even able to save the data using core data. The issue I'm running into is dialing the data in StorageViewController.

I'm able to create new cells everytime I save but when I click the cell and go to the Storageviewcontroller nothing populates. I'm not able to figure out the code for this.

Here is the code that goes in the DetailedViewController

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    //--------------Buttons and Labels for the project----------------

    @IBOutlet weak var locationText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var fileNameText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tagsText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Comments: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var lableMicrophones: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var LableRecorder: UITextField!

    @IBAction func importImage(_ sender: Any) {

        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self

        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        // image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(image, animated: true)
        {
            //After it is complete
        }

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapKIT: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var forCoordiantes: UITextField!


    //--------------Buttons and Labels for the project----------------


    // ------------------Declation on containers--------------------------

    let manager = CLLocationManager ()

    let mircophone_arr = [ "M/S Sennheiser MKH30 & DPA4060", "M/S Sennheiser MKH30 $ MKH20", "Stereo DPA4060s", "Rode NTG2", "Built In Microphone"]

    let Recorder_arr = ["Tascam DR-680", "Sound Device 702T", "Zoom H4n", "Zoom H2", "iPhone"]

    let my_pickerview = UIPickerView()

    var current_arr : [String] = []

    var active_textfield: UITextField!

    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    // ------------------Declation on containers--------------------------


    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = detailItem {
            if let label = detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.timestamp!.description
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        configureView()

        lableMicrophones.delegate = self
        LableRecorder.delegate = self

        my_pickerview.delegate = self
        my_pickerview.dataSource = self

        lableMicrophones.inputView = my_pickerview

        LableRecorder.inputView = my_pickerview

        //For mapkit

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()


        // Saving Data for location--------------------------------------------

        locationText.delegate = self
        fileNameText.delegate = self
        tagsText.delegate = self



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var detailItem: Event? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            configureView()
        }
    }

    //---------------------------formapkit Co-ordinates---------------------------------

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)

        mapKIT.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.mapKIT.showsUserLocation = true

        print(location.coordinate)

        forCoordiantes.text? = "\(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)"
    }

     //---------------------------formapkit Co-ordinates---------------------------------


    //----------------Hide keyboard when user touches outside------------------------------

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //----------------Hide keyboard when user touches outside------------------------------

    //-----------------user presses return key------------------------------------------------

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return (true)
    }

    //----------------Hide keyboard when user touches outside------------------------------

    //-----------------All 4 functions belong to picker view---------------------------------

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return current_arr.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return current_arr[row]
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        print("Selected item is", current_arr[row])
        active_textfield.text = current_arr[row]
    }

    //-----------------All 4 functions belong to picker view---------------------------------

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        active_textfield = textField

        switch textField {
        case lableMicrophones:
            current_arr = mircophone_arr
        case LableRecorder:
            current_arr = Recorder_arr
        default:
            print("Default")
        }
        return true
    }

    //------------------ Save Button function ----------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func saveFile(_ sender: Any) {
        if locationText.text != "" && fileNameText.text != "" {

            let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Event", into: context)
            newUser.setValue(self.locationText.text, forKey: "locationText")
            newUser.setValue(self.fileNameText.text, forKey: "fileNameText")

            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("error")
        }
    }

    //------------------ Save Button function ----------------------------------------------
}
```

Please help

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried to the reader of your question? Having a small code sample will greatly help us answer your question.

Comment: Please check the code in below comment. Now I'm tying to figure out what code goes in the StorageViewController